# Automate code coverage reports for any given week

Tags: automation, atlassian-crucible

I've had some trouble in my attempt to create automate code coverage reports across multiple projects at work in Crucible. It seems the code coverage panel grabs some data or manipulates some data in an algorithm which is different from just the delta-LOC stuff. In fact, I'm not even totally sure where the code coverage metrics even come from. It's definitely a mystery and quite frustrating. Is it possible that the delta-LOC metrics can be effected by reviewers cancelling a review?

This is the only thread I've found on the issue and it has not replies.
[Automated report generation for Crucible Review Coverage Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296708/automated-report-generation-for-crucible-review-coverage-report)

Any help is appreciated.